# Error trying to send an abstract data through libnl and generic netlink

Tags: c, netlink

I'm trying to send an abstract data using libnl and generic netlink, when I run the following code:

```
struct nl_msg *msg;
struct nl_data *abstract;
int err = -1;

if ((msg = nlmsg_alloc()) == NULL)
    return err;

if ((genlmsg_put(msg, ctrl->pid, NL_AUTO_SEQ, ctrl->genl_family, 
        0, NLM_F_REQUEST, CREATE_STATE, KLUA_VERSION) == NULL))
    return err;

if ((err = nla_put_string(msg, STATE_NAME, cmd->name)))
    return err;

if ((err = nl_send_auto(ctrl->sock, msg)) < 0)
    return err;

nlmsg_free(msg);
```

The kernel receives the message well. But if I change this code for this:

```
struct nl_msg *msg;
struct nl_data *abstract;
int err = -1;

if ((msg = nlmsg_alloc()) == NULL)
    return err;

if ((abstract = nl_data_alloc(cmd, sizeof(struct klua_nl_state))) == NULL)
    return err;

if ((genlmsg_put(msg, ctrl->pid, NL_AUTO_SEQ, ctrl->genl_family, 
        0, NLM_F_REQUEST, CREATE_STATE, KLUA_VERSION) == NULL))
    return err;
    
nla_put_data(msg, TEST_ATTR, abstract);

if ((err = nl_send_auto(ctrl->sock, msg)) < 0)
    return err;

nlmsg_free(msg);
```

By the way, my `TEST_ATTR` is defined as:

```
[TEST_ATTR] = {.type = NLA_UNSPEC}
```

Why the kernel isn't receiving my message if I'm changing just the payload of the message?
How do I do to send abstract data through generic netlink and libnl?

Comment: Is there a CRC (or similar) that you need to (re)calculate?

Comment: I made it now but the kernel still not receiving the messages, by the way, I know that the messages are being sent because I activated the debug function of libnl and the message is being sent with success, the problem is in the receiving part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Linux 5.2, the kernel's attribute validator function ([`validate_nla()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2/source/lib/nlattr.c#L157)) contains a [conditional](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2/source/lib/nlattr.c#L309) that essentially prohibits `NLA_UNSPEC` from being used.

I'm not really sure if disabling that validation is possible. The main user of `validate_nla()` [hardcodes](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2/source/include/net/netlink.h#L585) `validate` as `NL_VALIDATE_STRICT`, which [contains `NL_VALIDATE_UNSPEC`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2/source/include/net/netlink.h#L420).

But regardless, I suggest that you abstain from using `NLA_UNSPEC` to send C structs without proper serialization. It's a disaster waiting to happen. C has a gotcha called "[data structure padding](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/);" The gist of it is that C compilers are allowed to introduce garbage between the members of any structure. Thus, when you declare this:

```
struct test {
    __u16 a;
    __u32 b;
};
```

The compiler is technically allowed to mutate that during implementation into something like

```
struct test {
    __u16 a;
    unsigned char garbage[2];
    __u32 b;
};
```

See the problem? If your kernel module and your userspace client were generated by different compilers, or by the same compiler but with slightly different flags, **or even by slightly different versions of the same compiler**, the structures might differ and the kernel will receive garbage, no matter how correct your code looks.

Use [Nested Attributes](https://www.infradead.org/%7Etgr/libnl/doc/core.html#core_attr_nested) instead of `NLA_UNSPEC`. They will take care of alignment for you.